# Cannot fully edit column property in list setting

Tags: 2010, list, column

I want to edit the column property of "location" in my list, to make it required when submit the form. But when I click list setting, select "location" column,this is all I got:

"location" column setting page:
[image: "location" column setting page]

---

List setting page:
[image: List setting page]

---

Advanced setting page:
[image: Advanced setting page]

So, how do I make this column required when submit the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Advanced Settings and Enable the **Allow management of content types**.
2. Now you will see the content types associated with the list under the Settings section.
3. Click on **Item**.
4. Select the column.
5. Check the **Required radio button**.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But "allow management of content types" is already enabled.

Comment: Do you see Item under content types?

Comment: Really sorry but I'm not sure what you mean here, I've added more screen shot to show my current set up. Even "Allow management of content types" is enabled I still only see two lines in my column setting page.

Comment: Click on **Event** under content types.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I changed it in event page by clicking the "location" . Thank you!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you see when you click on Event?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to do this in Powershell.

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://sharepoint/" #change
$web= $site.OpenWeb()   
$spList = $web.GetList("/Lists/CustomList") #change 
$field = $spList.Fields["Location"]
$field.Required=$true
$field.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```